# Fossil identification

Tags: species-identification, fossil

I recently found a fossil which I am unable to identify. I believe it's a sea creature, but I don't know what kind. my best guess is some kind of shell or a [porpita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porpita_porpita).
I appreciate any help.
this is the image of the fossil.

[image: the fossil image]

The features of this fossil that I can describe are :

1- It seems to be circular

2- A pattern of lines which spread from the center

3- It does not seem to be curved (like a shell) — it looks flat

4- Dimensions are about 1.2 cm by 1.2 cm (circular)

5- This fossil was found in Iran/khouzestan

Another thing to mention is that where I found this fossil, I found other sea creature fossils like starfish and shells.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please edit into your question the dimensions of the fossil and where in the world the specimen comes from? These will greatly increase your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guide. I edited the question and added dims and location of discovery. @bob1

Comment: your question is a better fit over at https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ but you need to provide more information like a more exact location and if possible what other fossils can be found in the area,this is to find what geological time it is from.

Comment: without more information, best guess would be a natural cast of a fish vertebra.

Comment: Mah Es there is also https://www.reddit.com/r/fossilid/